# new mode for codemirror : Detecting an empty line in a stream

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I am trying to develop a simple mode for codemirror.
This mode will colour paragraphs alternatively in blue and green. A separation between paragraph is an empty line or a line containing only spaces.

Here is a version of the code that works, but with the big issue that empty lines are not detected:

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("rt", function() {
  return {
    startState: function() {return {state1: true};},
    token: function(stream, state) {
    if (stream.match(/\s\s*/)!=null){ # this fails to detect empty lines
        state.state1 = !state.state1;
    }
    stream.skipToEnd();
    if (state.state1)  { return "status1"; } 
    return "status2";
    }
  };
});
```

if I apply it to the following text:

```
line 1
line 2 # the next line is just a backspace and is not detected

line 3
line 4 # the next line is a few spaces followed by a backspace, it is detected

line 5
line 6
```

it colors from line 1 to line 4 in one color and line 5 to line 6 in another, which is expected.

I am trying to find a way to update my code so that it detects the empty line between line 2 and line 3. Any way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of codemirror says:

> By default, **blank lines are simply skipped** when tokenizing a document.
>   For languages that have significant blank lines, you can define a
>   **blankLine(state) method** on your mode that will get called whenever a
>   blank line is passed over, so that it can update the parser state.

(http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi)

The following code works (blankLine function added):

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("rt", function() {
  return {
    startState: function() {return {state1: true};},
    blankLine: function (state){ state.state1 = !state.state1; },
    token: function(stream, state) {
    console.log(stream)
    if (stream.match(/^\s*$/)!=null){
        state.state1 = !state.state1;
    }
    stream.skipToEnd();
    if (state.state1)  { return "status1"; } 
    return "status2";
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can detect backspace with `[\b]` in javascript regexp: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

BTW `/\s\s*/` can be simplified to `/\s+/` however if you want to detect "an empty line or a line containing only spaces", you can use `/\s*/`.

Also if you don't care about the actual result array of the regular expression, you can use `test()` instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

You can use `^` to indicate the beginning of the line and `$` for the line end.

So the code will be **roughly**  like this:

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("rt", function() {
  return {
    startState: function() {
      return {
        state1: true
      };
    },
    token: function(stream, state) {
      if ( /^\s*$/m.test(stream) ) {
        state.state1 = !state.state1;
      }
      stream.skipToEnd();
      return state.state1 ? "status1" : "status2";
    }
  };
});
```

The m flag is used to specify that a multiline input string should be treated as multiple lines. If the m flag is used, ^ and $ match at the start or end of any line within the input string instead of the start or end of the entire string. Example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_m.asp

Comment: I am afraid this results in lines alternating colors, not paragraphs ^^;

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot the `^` and `$` from the regex. Can you try this one?

Comment: still no success. "Empty lines" do not seem to go through the function at all, as if codemirror was somehow skipping them before feedding the function ...

Comment: (what I mean is that if I had console.log(stream) at the beginning at the function, the "empty line" does not show up.)

Comment: How about filing an issue on Codemirror's github? It seems to be more active than Stackoverflow: https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues